# eslint should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, tdd, mocha.js, enzyme

Either I don't understand `dependencies` vs. `devDependencies` in node 100% yet or eslint is just wrong here (not capable of analyzing this correctly):

```
   3:1   error  'chai' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies              import/no-extraneous-dependencies
   4:1   error  'chai-enzyme' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies       import/no-extraneous-dependencies
   5:1   error  'enzyme' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies            import/no-extraneous-dependencies
   7:1   error  'sinon' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies             import/no-extraneous-dependencies
   9:1   error  'redux-mock-store' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies  import/no-extraneous-dependencies
```

These are test dependencies, so why is it saying that they should be listed in `dependencies`?

Additional note: We're using Travis as our CI so I don't know if it makes a difference for that at all either.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Solved it with adding this to my `.eslintrc`:

`"import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", {"devDependencies": true}]`

[[no-extraneous-dependencies] Add exceptions? #422](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/422)

**Based on this user's reply**:

> you could set the option devDependencies: true in an .eslintrc in your
>   test folder:
>
> rules:   import/no-extraneous-dependencies: [error, { devDependencies:
>   true }] Then you'll get reports of any packages referenced that are
>   not included dependencies or devDependencies. **Then you get the
>   goodness of the rule, with no noise from the disable comments**.
>
> I think that might work for you? This is how I would use the rule, in
>   your case, since you have your test code separated into a test
>   directory.

**Also this post was helpful to confirm I wasn't insane to not want some of these in my dependencies list**: [Sharable ESLint Config](https://medium.com/defmethod-works/sharable-eslint-config-b96af3b93960)

Comment: Make sure to restart your node.js server with CTRL-C and a `npm start` it for this to catch on

Comment: Have a look at my answer if you want to disable the lint only for certain files (i.e. tests).

Comment: This could lead to missing dependencies when running in non-development mode. I think @magic_al answer is a better alternative.

Comment: the answer of @magic_al is better as it keeps the eslint config in a single place - easier to comprehend and maintain.

Answer (score 131):

If you want to allow imports of `devDependencies` in **test files only** you can use an `array of globs`, as the [documentation](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-extraneous-dependencies.md) of `no-extraneous-dependencies` states:

> When using an array of globs, the setting will be set to true (no errors reported) if the name of the file being linted matches a single glob in the array, and false otherwise.

The following setting will disable the lint for test files only.

```
"import/no-extraneous-dependencies":[
  "error",
  {
     "devDependencies":[
        "**/*.test.ts",
        "**/*.test.tsx"
     ]
  }
]
```

That way imports from `devDependencies` are still reported as errors.

Comment: Anyone have a clue why adding that yields, ```Unexpected top-level property "import/no-extraneous-dependencies"``` in VScode...  While the reported error is ```'yaml' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies. eslint(import/no-extraneous-dependencies)```

Comment: @Marvin do you have that as a property of the `rules` object in your eslint file?

Comment: @DavidGilbertson Hmm.  I thought I had, but trying to add it right now, it works fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it by using

```
 'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': [
      'error',
      {
        projectDependencies: false,
      },
    ],
```

Comment: Gives me error: `Value {"projectDependencies":false} should NOT have additional properties.`

Comment: @pmiranda Maybe it's just because of the trailing comma inside the object (after "false" here: `projectDependencies: false,`)

Answer (score 5):

(2023 Answer)

I fixed it by restarting my code editor.

Similar to the suggestion to restart ESLint, I restarted my code editor and the error went away.

Comment: Gosh I should have done this first...

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve it by adding the missing packages (in my case, Typescript and Storybook) to my `plugins` directory in `.eslintrc`.

I give the specifics in this post: [ESLint error: '@storybook/react' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70585870/eslint-error-storybook-react-should-be-listed-in-the-projects-dependencies/70585871#70585871)

Comment: In another case, I had 'react' in node_modules but it wasn't finding it for some reason so I deleted node_modules and reinstalled of them with `yarn` and that solved it.

Answer (score 3):

By me It was fixed by adding this:

```
"import/no-extraneous-dependencies": "off"
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it just turns the rule off!!!

Answer (score 1):

finally found solution.
to .eslintrc pass it like this:

```
"import/no-extraneous-dependencies":[
  "error",
  {
     "devDependencies":[
        "**/*.test.ts",
        "**/*.test.tsx"
     ]
  }
]
```

thanks to @magic_al answer and than restart your ESLint server. (for those running on VSCode press F1 and than search for `ESLint: Restart ESLint Server`)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, with latest eslint + import plugin, I needed to DELETE the rule customizations from my eslintrc.