# eslint 'html-webpack-plugin' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies. (import/no-extraneous-dependencies)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, node-modules, commonjs

In my Vs code editor, i am getting following error in simple require statement like:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
```

Error: **[eslint] 'html-webpack-plugin' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies. (import/no-extraneous-dependencies)**

Can anyone explain what is no-extraneous-dependencies and why it is giving me this error in simple require statement in my webpack config. I went through this link : [eslint should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939304/eslint-should-be-listed-in-the-projects-dependencies-not-devdependencies) but it was not much helpful as it did not explain why i am adding that line.

My eslintrc.json file:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier", "prettier/react"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You just need to tell eslint that it's ok to require dev dependency in webpack.

You can create `.eslintrc` in your webpack folder with

```
rules:
  import/no-extraneous-dependencies: [error, { devDependencies: true }]
```

This will prevent the error from appearing.

Alternatively you can just set

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); // eslint-disable-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
```

to disable only this line

Answer (score 3):

In your `.eslintrc.json` include `webpack.config.js` in `devDependencies`:

```
"rules": {
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [
      "error",
      {
        "devDependencies": [
          "**/*.test.ts?(x)",
          "**/*.spec.ts?(x)",
          "**/test-utils.ts",
          "webpack.config.js"
        ]
      }
    ],
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `"type": "module"` to your `package.json`, then you can use ES6 import without this error/warning.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.