# ESLint error: '@storybook/react' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies

Tags: eslint, storybook, eslintrc

After installing Storybook into a React.js app with ESLint, the VSCode linter wasn't picking up the `@storybook/react` imports in the examples `.stories.js` files.

It is giving me the following error:

```
'@storybook/react' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies.eslintimport/no-extraneous-dependencies
```

Answer (score 21):

I was able to get the linter warnings to go away by adding an ignore rule my `.eslintrc` file:

```
"rules": {
  "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [
      "error",
      {
        "devDependencies": [
          "**/*.stories.*",
          "**/.storybook/**/*.*"
        ],
        "peerDependencies": true
      }
    ]
}
```

There is a good example here: https://github.com/storybookjs/linter-config/blob/master/eslint.config.js

Comment: Thanks for this. I was running into this problem with vite.config.ts, which I just had to put in the devDependencies array as you showed.

Answer (score 8):

I recently had the same issue. I solved it by restarting the ESLint server.
To do this, open the command palette by typing **Ctrl+Shift+P**, then search for the command **ESLint: Restart ESLint Server** and hit enter.

Comment: If you are using WebStorm on another JetBrains IDE, this https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14119-eslint-restart-service-action plugin may be helpful. Also, according to their roadmap https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2024/01/2024-1-roadmap/, this functionality may implemented in a new language service widget.